# How to get access to (embedded in) Maven console in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is possible to access Maven (embedded) console in Eclipse like in shell (linux shell, windows cmd.exe) to run custom maven commands (mvn archetype:create.... etc) ? I'm using m2e, but can run Maven commands only by GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using maven console with m2eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848002/using-maven-console-with-m2eclipse)

Answer (score 6):

You can run custom maven commands directly from Eclipse by doing:

```
 Run -> Run Configurations... -> Maven Build
```

You'll need just some Maven plugin for Eclipse like m2e.

Answer (score 5):

maybe you can use "external tools" function to do it.

see:

1. In Eclipse, choose “Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations
2. In "Program", click “New Launch Configuration”
3. Config your console name, location, working directory
4. "run"

sorry for no images, because my reputation is below 10.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend shell plugin for Eclipse: Wicked shell (http://www.wickedshell.net/)

Comment: Wicked shell open something like cmd.exe, but to use mvn command is required to install mvn separately. Is possible to use that embedded in Eclipse ?

Comment: You can always set MVN_HOME environment variable to embedded maven directory.

Comment: Where is that the embedded maven directory ? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't know about any Eclipse plugin to do that :(

A long time ago (in the Maven 1 era) there was a Maven goal called "console" that allowed you to execute goals in a pre-loaded maven instance. But that feature was discontinued in Maven 2.

For new versions of Maven (Maven 3), the folks at Sonatype made a Maven Shell which I think will do what you want: http://shell.sonatype.org/index.html