# Perform "mvn dependency:tree" *within Eclipse*

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project which I program within Eclipse. In Eclipse, everything works, but when building it with Maven, I get a NoSuchMethodError on a call to a third-party jar. So I suspect that Eclipse uses a different version of that jar when compiling. I can see which version of what Maven uses, but I'd like to see which version of what *Eclipse* uses. I don't see how to perform a "mvn dependency:tree" from within Eclipse, such that I would see the result form "Eclipse's point-of-view".

The project was created using "File/Import.../Existing Maven Project".

I am using "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers", Version: "Kepler Service Release 1"

To perform *any* Maven command from Eclipse, I just found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858495/how-to-get-access-to-embedded-in-maven-console-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open the pom.xml you want to learn about.  This is a multipane editor.  One of the panes shows the dependencies and how they are resolved.

Comment: For some reason, POMs open by default in some "plain" text editor in Eclipse, so I forgot about that added functionality.

Comment: Then you've changed the default behavior.

Comment: Note for future readers: there is a completely separate representation directly opening in the "Outline" window. This only shows what's in the pom in a neat way. What you would typically be looking for is the "Dependencies" or "Dependency Hierarchy" tab in the main window.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you installed m2e ( previously called as m2eclipse ) plugin.
If Eclipse opens pom.xml as plain text, then click the pom.xml and click mouse-right button for pop-up menu. You'll see "Open With" -> " Maven POM Editor". 
Within Maven Pom Editor, you can check those dependencies in either "dependencies" or "dependencies hierarchy".

Answer (score 5):

as shown below, open pom.xml and tab on "Dependency Hirarchy"

[image: maven pom dependency hierrchy]

Answer (score 1):

Check your .classpath file and modify that add "attributes" under the "classpathentry" to use maven dependency in the build path.

Here is the example of .classpath

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

Comment: Hi. I asked the question long ago. We already have "maven.pomderived" configured, and do not have that problem anymore, so I cannot judge wether your answer is useful or not.